# Can you stream photos from a PC to an iPad?

Tags: ipad, applications

I have more photos then I want to download onto the iPad.  Is there a favorite app that allows users to browse photos from a Windows7 machine to view on my iPad over wifi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FileBrowser](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/filebrowser-access-files-on/id364738545?mt=8) from the App Store lets you browse your shared network folders.