# Stream photos from iTunes to iPad

Tags: itunes, ipad, photos, streaming

I have enabled **Home Sharing** on a PC (Windows 7). I am successfully streaming **Video** and **Music** to my **iPad**.

Now the fun things is that I have found out that I can't **stream photos** from **PC** to **iPad** normally. I have the way for it via **DropBox** but that's not a **WiFi**. It could take sometime for me to normally stream photos.

I can't belive that I can stream **Video** and **Music** but I can't stream **Photos**.

There was a menu item on **iTunes -> Advanced -> Choose Photos to Share...**

But this seems not what I want (it works great but with **Apple TV**, but not with **iPad**)

How is that possible???

Alright, that's possible. But is there a way to stream photos in a such simple and logical way?

P.S: Similiar looking question "http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26250/can-you-stream-photos-from-a-pc-to-an-ipad" is not really similiar.

Comment: Apple TV > Computer > iDevice. Apple considers devices with smaller displays to be ‘lesser’ devices when it comes to streaming.

Comment: @duci9y but you can stream videos

Comment: Oh I’m sorry. You had written “stream” in the title and I automatically assumed that you meant AirPlay but now I see you meant Home Sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you actually can. Home Sharing does have photo sharing support (as you've discovered with your Apple TV), but I don't believe you can stream photos from a computer to an iPad. Movies, TV Shows, Podcasts and the rest, but I don't remember photos from a computer *to* an iPad were ever supported.

The only way to do it would be to use a third-party app or use iCloud with *Photo Stream*, if you can work within its limitations.

Comment: I find this thing ridiculous. Being able to stream video, music, etc. and not being able to stream Photos O_o. Apple way? :D ah...it's sad ;(

Comment: It does seem a bit bizarre, but if we're being charitable, I suppose it wasn't as big a use case. Streaming _from_ iOS devices or streaming photos to an Apple TV is pretty handy because chances are the TV is the biggest display you have. Whereas your computer is probably bigger-screened than your iPad, so why not view photos on that? Of course, this theory falls down a little when you can stream video but not photos. I guess they want you to use Photo Stream, which isn't too bad. You can get the iCloud Control Panel for Windows (http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1455) which is worth a look.

Comment: I'd rather use DropBox for that. And iCloud is Computer -> Internet -> your device and now Computer -> your device

Comment: That works too, though Dropbox for iOS doesn't come with LAN sync unlike the desktop clients so it's still Computer -> Internet -> Device.

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking about when typing "and now Computer -> your device". I meant that I want to achieve that "Computer -> your device"